# Clamp iterator value to end() with std::min

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector with n Strings in it. Now lets say I want to "page" or "group" those strings in a map.

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> TStringVec;
TStringVec myVec;

//.. fill myVecwith n elements

typedef std::map<int, TStringVec>> TPagedMap;
TPagedMap myMap;

int ItemsPerPage = 3 // or whatever
int PagesRequired = std::ceil(myVec.size() / nItemsPerPage);
for (int Page = 0; Page < NumPagesMax; ++Page)
{
    TStringVec::const_iterator Begin = myVec.begin() + (ItemsPerPage * Page);
    TStringVec::const_iterator End = myVec.begin() + ItemsPerPage * (Page+1);
    myMap[Page] = TStringVec(Begin, End);
}
```

One can easily spot the problem here. When determining the end iterator, I risk leaving the allocated space by the vector.

Quick example: 5 elements in the vector, ItemsPerPage is 3. That means we need a total of 2 pages in the map to group all elements.

Now when hitting the last iteration, begin is pointing at myVec[3] but end is "pointing" to myVec[6]. Remember, myVec only has 5 elements.

Could this case be safely handled by swapping

```
TStringVec::const_iterator End = myVec.begin() + ItemsPerPage * (Page+1);
```

with

```
TStringVec::const_iterator End = std::min(myVec.begin() + ItemsPerPage * (Page+1), myVec.end());
```

It compiles of course, and it *seems* to work. But I'm not sure if this can be considered a **safe** thing to do. Any advice or a definitive answer?

I think the question is... Is a value "past" .end() guaranteed to be larger than the adress returned by .end()?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: of course, a `if` check beforehand could solve the problem, but I'm looking for a more *elegant* solution.

Comment: Why iterate over pages, calculating `Begin` and `End`? Why not iterate over strings, calculating `Page`?

Comment: Well, you would have the same problem, wouldn't you?

Comment: No, because you can add pages to the map without danger.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: If you iterate over pages and calculate `Begin` and `End`, you might dereference a pointer past the end of the vector, which is UB. If you iterate over strings and calculate pages, there is no way to run past the end of the vector, and you can add pages to the map without danger of running past the end of the map.

Comment: But that would involve an if condition to check if i need a new page right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your proposed replacement:

1. You are potentially creating an iterator past the end-iterator, which is UB.
2. For some unfathomable reason, you want to stop at `end() - 1`?? Everywhere else, you properly use half-open ranges.

What you want is more like

```
auto End = myVec.cbegin() + std::min(ItemsPerPage * (Page + 1), myVec.size());
```

Also take note that I used `auto` to avoid needlessly specifying complicated type-names.

As an aside, using `std::ceil` on an integer is not very useful conceptually, at least the compiler will likely optimize out the round-trip through `double`.

Comment: ad 1: Thats the problem I'm aware of
ad 2: Thanks for pointing that out, corrected the misstake.
Thanks for the additional remarks, you are right.
But is i guaranteed to work with  std::min?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help and for implicitly pointing me to cbegin(). I didnt know that existed.

Answer (score 3):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may use `chunk` view:

```
std::vector<std::string> myVec = /*...*/;

const int ItemsPerPage = 3 // or whatever

std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>>> myMap;
int counter = 0;
for (const auto& page : myVec | ranges::view::chunk(ItemsPerPage)) {
    myMap[counter++] = page;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f904a316dd753ed3)

Comment: Thanks! I've never seen this syntax before with the | though

Comment: You can overload most operator including `operator |`. It has been done to allow intuitive chaining (instead of `f(g(a, h(x)))` we have `x | h | g(a) | f`).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!